# What is wrong with this GREP?

Tags: bash, grep

This is my text file:

```
line A
line B
line C
```

Now I'm trying to find the line that ends with A:

```
cat foo.txt | grep 'A$'
```

BTW:

```
$ grep --version
GNU grep 2.6.3
```

Comment: what's wrong with the above grep? does it print nothing?

Comment: Are you on Windows, perhaps?  What end-of-line character is being used?  If you run `cat -e foot.txt` do you see `^M` or `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your grep command. But there may be a chance of space characters exists after the last `A`. so use the below grep command.

```
grep 'A\s*$' file
```

`\s` matches any kind of horizontal or vertical whitespace character.

**OR**

You could use the POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` to match any kind of space character.

```
grep 'A[[:space:]]*$' file
```

Comment: `\s` only works in newer versions of GNU `grep`. Use `[[:space:]]` for portability.

Answer (score 0):

If last character is always a single one, this `awk` should do:

```
awk '$NF=="A"' file
line A
```

It test if last field equals to `A`
This will also work if there are hidden spaces/tabs after last character.